# Is the state of recoil reset to the intial value when the component renders?

Tags: reactjs, state-management, recoiljs

I using recoil in a react project to manage state and I would like to know if the state is reset automatically by the library when the component unmounts or not. The use case is that I use useRecoilState to get the state from recoil and then I change it within the component. When I go out of the component and get back to it again, I see the state is being back to the initial value, is this an intended behavior or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recoil should persist through the app. Are you possibly resetting the value on component render?

Comment: No I am not. I have been stuck at this issue for so long and I could not find a solution so far.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to share with us?

Comment: Sounds like your `RecoilRoot` might not be high up enough in your app hierarchy, and that it's being deleted and re-created.